# PPTP won't connect error 628

Tags: linux, networking, centos, vpn, pptp

```
vim /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client        server  secret                  IP addresses
#*       pptpd   34fg3g93jgij3g    *
```

and

```
vim /etc/radiusclient/servers
#Server Name or Client/Server pair              Key
24.211.2.16  34fg3g93jgij3g
```

options file

```
vim /etc/ppp/options.pptpd
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
proxyarp
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
lock
nobsdcomp
novj
novjccomp
nologfd
plugin radius.so
plugin radattr.so
```

and

```
vim /etc/pptpd.conf
option /etc/ppp/options.pptpd
localip 10.0.0.1
remoteip 10.0.0.10-100
```

ran the following iptables

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
```

my connection settings:
http://i46.tinypic.com/2powpkz.png

Any ideas why I can't get pptp to connect? I have OpenVPN working just fine but PPTP seems to be giving me some issues

/var/log/messages

```
Jan  9 22:54:30 vpn pptpd[3856]: CTRL: Client 34.29.38.2 control connection started
Jan  9 22:54:30 vpn pptpd[3856]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Jan  9 22:54:30 vpn pppd[3857]: Plugin radius.so loaded.
Jan  9 22:54:30 vpn pppd[3857]: RADIUS plugin initialized.
Jan  9 22:54:30 vpn pppd[3857]: Plugin radattr.so loaded.
Jan  9 22:54:30 vpn pppd[3857]: RADATTR plugin initialized.
Jan  9 22:54:30 vpn pppd[3857]: Plugin /usr/lib64/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Jan  9 22:54:30 vpn pppd[3857]: pppd 2.4.4 started by root, uid 0
Jan  9 22:54:30 vpn pppd[3857]: Using interface ppp0
Jan  9 22:54:30 vpn pppd[3857]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
Jan  9 22:54:31 vpn pppd[3857]: Modem hangup
Jan  9 22:54:31 vpn pppd[3857]: Connection terminated.
Jan  9 22:54:31 vpn pppd[3857]: Exit.
```